# How to access a variable defined in view-model from view file

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a view-model file where upon the execution of loadCustomer function I set a variable to true.

```
 loadCustomer: function () {
     CustomerViewModel.set("CustomerDetails",CustomerViewModel.CustomerDataSource._data[0]);
     var initialCustomerLoad = true;
 },
```

How can I access initialCustomerLoad from my view file? I want to be able to check if initialCustomerLoad is false then do something...

```
if (initialPatientDataLoad != true) {
    // my business logic will be going here.              
}
```

How do I go about this? How do I access initialPatientDataLoad  from my view file ? Help appreciated!

Comment: Trying to make sure I understand this, but your view has javascript in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try design your view model to be like this

**customer.viewmodel.js**

```
var CustomerViewModel = function() {
    // ..some property..
    this.loaded = false;
}

CustomerViewModel.prototype.loadCustomer = function() {
    var self = this;

    //..your operation here
    self.loaded = true;
    return self;
}
```

Usage in 
**customer.view.js**

```
var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel();

viewModel.loadCustomer(data);

if(!viewModel.loaded) {
   //..your code here
}
// futher implementation
```